# How To Get Particular Values From JSON and Plot on Map view Using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, mkmapview

I need to get particular values from below `JSON` response, The values are I have mentioned below

```
Reg no: (Need to show callout)
Lat :  (Need to use drop pin on map)
Long :  (Need to use drop pin on map)
Name : (Need to show callout)
Age : (Need to show callout)
```

`NOTE :` The school of array values getting from server so It will Increase based on A , B and C categories. Its not static!

```
{
    A =     {
        school =         (
                        {
               reg_no = 1;
     latitude = "22.345";
                longitude = "-12.4567";

               student =                 (
                                        {
                        name = "akila";
                        age = "23";

                       }
                );
                city = "<null>";
                state = TN;
            },
                                    {
               reg_no = 2;
               latitude = "22.345";
               longitude = "-12.4567";

               student =                 (
                                        {
                        name = "sam";
                        age = "23";

                       }
                );
                city = "<null>";
                state = TN;
            },                                   {
               reg_no = 3;
               latitude = "22.345";
               longitude = "-12.4567";

               student =                 (
                                        {
                        name = "lansi";
                        age = "23";

                       }
                );
                city = "<null>";
                state = TN;
            }
       );
        Schoolname = "Good School";
        categories = school;
   };
}
```

My Code (Below code not working) :

```
 if (data) {

           NSError *error;
            NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves | NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
            NSDictionary *response = JSON[@"response"];

           for (NSDictionary *entry in response[@"A"][@"school"]) {
                NSString *regNo = entry[@"reg_no"];
                NSString *name = entry[@"student"][@"name"];
                NSString *age = entry[@"student"][@"age"];
                double latitude = [entry[@"latitude"] doubleValue];
                double longitude = [entry[@"longitude"] doubleValue];
                MKPointAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
                myAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
                myAnnotation.title = name;
                myAnnotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Reg: %@, Age: %@", regNo, age];
                [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];

            }
```

Comment: Will you please provide exact json string ? So we can understand that what you want format of the object. this is not valid json string.

Comment: @CrazyDeveloper - Now I have updated check now!

Answer (score 0):

Try NSJSONSerialization

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

if (!jsonArray) {
  NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
} else {
   for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray) {
      NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`NSJSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/) to parse the JSON, then you can access the values you need in a loop using Objective-C's [subscripting syntax](http://nshipster.com/object-subscripting/). Once you have all these, you can add the entries as `MKAnnotation`s on an `MKMapView` to get what you want. Note that `MKAnnotation` is a protocol, so you'll need to create a class that implements it.

```
MKMapView *mapView = [MKMapView new];
NSDictionary *parsedJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
for (NSDictionary *entry in parsedJSON[@"A"][@"school") {
    NSString *regNo = entry[@"reg_no"];
    NSString *name = entry[@"student"][@"name"];
    NSString *age = entry[@"student"][@"age"];
    double latitude = [entry[@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    double longitude = [entry[@"longitude"] doubleValue];
    id<MKAnnotation> annotation = [/*class implementing MKAnnotation*/ new];
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
    annotation.title = name;
    annotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Reg: %@, Age: %@", regNo, age];
    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

Comment: Ok I will try and let you know. Thank you! Btw     id<MKAnnotation> annotation = [/*class implementing MKAnnotation*/ new];
what I want to implement here ?@Tim Johsen

Comment: NSError *error;
            NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves | NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
            NSDictionary *response = JSON[@"response"];
            
            NSLog(@"RESPONSE FOR MAP PLOTINGS : %@",response);
            
            for (NSDictionary *entry in response[@"A"][@"school"]) { } here I am not getting any values?

Comment: The error you're getting makes me think you're not using valid JSON. You can use http://jsonlint.com/ to see if your JSON is valid or where its issues are.

Comment: You need to create a class that implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol, the class is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

u should iterate entry[@"student"] to get the data of every student
entry[@"student"][@"name"] will get no data even if entry[@"student"] only have one

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON file that you have provided for lacks of 'response' key in it. However, you are searching as `NSDictionary *response = JSON[@"response"];`. That could be the problem. Other than this, you can try **NSDictionary**'s **valueForKey:** method to search deeper in your JSON.